# Refreshing the listview of MainActivity after finishing another activity

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, baseadapter

I have troubles with refreshing my listview adapter after I close another activity. I am making program for delivery notes and my main screen is a list with notes. My problem is that when I add a new note(which I am making in another activity) the new note is note appearing on the list. It appears only after rotation of the screen or refreshing the whole program. Here is my code for the MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle SavedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (SavedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        // Get our UI controls from the loaded layout
        Button addButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AddButton);
        // Loading the already saved notes from external file
        objectToSerialize = new ObjectToSerialize();
        serializer = new Serializer ();
        var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists (path + "outputFile.txt")) {
            deserialize ();
        }
        //Displaying the Notes in a custom made ListView 
        objListItem = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);
        objListItem.Adapter = new MonoBaseAdapter2 (this, _lstNoteInfo);
        objListItem.FastScrollEnabled = true;

        objListItem.ItemClick += delegate(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {
            var itemClicked = new Intent(this,typeof(InfoActivity));
            itemClicked.PutExtra("File name",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].ImageID);
            itemClicked.PutExtra("Date",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].Date);
            itemClicked.PutExtra("Type",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].Type);
            itemClicked.PutExtra("Supplier",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].Supplier);
            itemClicked.PutExtra("Amount",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].Amount);
            itemClicked.PutExtra("Info",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].AddInfo);
            StartActivity (itemClicked);
        };

        addButton.Click += delegate {
            StartActivity (typeof(AddActivity));
        };

    }
```

I have tried with overriding onResume() and using the invalidate(), notifyDataSetChanged(), refreshDrawableState(); methods, but none of them worked. Maybe I am not using them as I should I don't know .. I would appreciate any ideas! :)

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I said in my question that I have used it already in my onResume() method but it's not working ..

Comment: Where are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    posts.clear();
    posts.addAll(tempPosts);
    postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I use this in my project, works like a charm.

Post is my List, and tempPost is list where I save edited post list.

Comment: Pleased to hear that ;)

Answer (score 1):

For an ArrayAdapter, notifyDataSetChanged only works if you use the add(), insert(), remove(), and clear() on the Adapter.

When an ArrayAdapter is constructed, it holds the reference for the List that was passed in. If you were to pass in a List that was a member of an Activity, and change that Activity member later, the ArrayAdapter is still holding a reference to the original List. The Adapter does not know you changed the List in the Activity.

Your choices are:

Use the functions of the ArrayAdapter to modify the underlying List (add(), insert(), remove(), clear(), etc.)
Re-create the ArrayAdapter with the new List data. (Uses a lot of resources and garbage collection.)
Create your own class derived from BaseAdapter and ListAdapter that allows changing of the underlying List data structure.
Use the notifyDataSetChanged() every time the list is updated. To call it on the UI-Thread, use the runOnUiThread() of Activity. Then, notifyDataSetChanged() will work.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer man ! Now I know my problem, I tried clearing my list and making a new list which is the same like the old one + the new note. Then I add all of the objects in the old list and finally used the notifyDataSetChanged() method. Finally my problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Try StartActivityForResult instead, then you can @Override the onActivityResult method and do some stuff there (like notifyDataSetChanged() or adding your new row)